# Get error code of last shell command

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

Using `bash`, the exit code of the last thing that executed is stored in the `$?` shell variable:

```
foo
bar
echo $?  # prints exit code of `bar`

baz
echo $?  # prints exit code of `baz`
```

Is there an equivalent way to get this value if I'm running a script in `cmd` under Windows? (Note: resorting to things like  running a Python script which then invokes its own library functions is not what I'm after here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%ERRORLEVEL%` is the equivalent in Windows     .

Comment: Keep in mind though, that this can fail if there is an actual environment variable named `%ERRORLEVEL%`. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx. So for added robustness you may want to delete the variable before accessing the pseudo-variable.